# Dedekind finite union of Dedekind finite sets is Dedekind finite

Tags: set-theory

I could use some help proving the following:

Let $A$
  be a Dedekind Finite set of pairwise disjoint Dedekind finite sets $\left(\mbox{i.e each}\, a\in A\,\mbox{is a Dedekind Finite set}\right)$
  show that $\bigcup A$
  is Dedekind Finite.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT: Let $S=\bigcup A$, and suppose that there is an injection $\omega\to S$. For $a\in A$ let $$N_a=\{k\in\omega:f(k)\in a\}\;.$$ Show that $N_a$ is finite for each $a\in A$ and use that result to construct an injection from $\omega$ to $A$, contradicting the Dedekind-finiteness of $A$.

Comment: I got the first part but I'm not sure how to construct the injection. I assume this is where I use the fact the sets in $A$ are pairwise disjoint. 
I don't want to use the Axiom of Choice since under AC I already know that Dedekind Finite is equivalent to finite and then the whole idea of the proof is moot.

Comment: @Serpahimz: Let $A_0=\{a\in A:N_a\ne\varnothing\}$, and for $a\in A_0$ let $n(a)=\min N_a$. Let $N=\{n(a):a\in A_0\}$. There’s a bijection from $\omega$ to $N$, which you can compose with ... what?

Comment: I think to finish I compose it with $g:N\to A$
  defined by $g\left(n\left(a\right)\right)=a$ and I show that it is well defined by using the fact the sets are pairwise disjoint and thus for all $a\neq b$
  I know that $n\left(a\right)\neq n\left(b\right)$
 
 *Hope I won't make a fool of myself*

Comment: @Serpahimz: You’ve got it.

Comment: One small thing I'm not sure about is why there is a bijection between $\omega$ and N. Isn't it possible that N is finite?

Comment: @Serpahimz: If $N$ were finite, $A_0$ would be finite, and some $N_a$ would be infinite, which is impossible.

Comment: Right got it all sorted now :)
Thanks a lot Brian!

Comment: @Serpahimz: You’re welcome!

Comment: What a good proof and such a good discussion. Wasn't able to understand proof first but ultimately got any single hint from here only

Comment: @Logic: That’s correct. I’d have to think about what happens when they’re not disjoint; it’s been quite a while since I last worked with this stuff.

Comment: Please let me know, when you come up with the argument!

Comment: Actually the proof in herrlichs book shows that this is not true in the disjoint case!

Comment: $Y=\bigcup_{x\in X} Y_{x}$, and $X$ is a dedekind finite set, so $Y$ is a dedekind infinite set which is a dedekind finite union of dedekind finite sets.

Comment: @Logic: Ah, you’re right: I misinterpreted something in Herrlich. I’m going to delete my earlier comments to you. Herrlich does indeed show that it needn’t be true in the **non**-disjoint case.

Comment: Great! That clears everything up, Thanks!

Comment: @Logic: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 3):

If $B\subseteq\bigcup A$ is a countably infinite set, then $B_a=B\cap a$ is a Dedekind-finite set for every $a\in A$.

Show that every partition of a countably infinite set into Dedekind-finite sets is finite, and one of the parts has to be countably infinite.

Deduce that there is some $a\in A$ such that $B_a$ is countably infinite which is a contradiction to Dedekind-finiteness of $a$.

---

To prove the fact in the middle note that we may assume that the infinite set is $\mathbb N$ and that a partition is merely a surjection. Show, if so, that every surjection from $\mathbb N$ onto a Dedekind-finite set implies that the range is finite. (**Hint:** If $f\colon\mathbb N\to X$ is a surjection then there is an injection $g\colon X\to\mathbb N$.)

Comment: I used the previously suggested proof for my exercise (simply because it was first and I already started typing it) but this is also an elegant solution.
Thanks a lot for replying!

Comment: Note that both proofs are actually the same. It just might be slightly easier to use one over the other depending on how you defined a Dedekind-finite set.

Comment: This doesn’t seem to be using choice, the hint bit can be established without choice since $\mathbb{N}$ is well ordered, but  in Herrlichs book disaster 4.3 specifically states the Dedekind finite union of dedekind finite sets can be dedekind infinite without choice, but isn’t that a contradiction? [Sorry for asking so many questions but I am trying to get my head around Dedekind finite sets and almost all related posts have your answers on them! :)]

Comment: @Logic: If you read the actual proof in Herrlich you will notice that the correct disaster is "A D-Infinite union of D-finite sets can be D-finite".

Comment: Thanks that makes sense! This answer does use the disjointness of the sets though,  so what if the sets weren't disjoint? [I realize that its possible without choice for the union *not to* inject into the disjoint union ,right?]

Comment: @Logic I have not assumed the union is disjoint.

Comment: Don't you need the disjointness in order to asccoiate a partition with a surjection?

Comment: @Logic: No, since $B$ is countable. Just refine it as necessary.

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand how to refine it to make it disjoint...

Comment: Is the refineation a trivial argument, can you please give a hint. I tried but failed, perhaps some sort of recursion is needed?

Comment: @Logic: The point is that a Dedekind-finite subset of a countable set is finite. And any collection of finite subsets of a countable set is countable.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Is the following correct? So we know that the union  ${\bigcup}_{a \in A} (B\cap a)=B $, is countably infinite, and since $B\cap a$ is dedekind finite and a subset of a countably infinite set, it must be finite, now consider the collection $M=\{ x: x=B\cap a\}$, it is atmost countable, since it's a subset of the set of all finite subsets of $B$ ,which is a countably infinite set, but $M$ is also dedekind finite, since there is an injection from $M$ to $A$, so it must be finite, but the finite union of finite sets is finite and so we have a contradiction$(\bot)$.

Comment: @Logic: Yeah, that checks out.

Comment: Ouch! I have a question from my own argument, I just realised it’s not clear to me that there is an injection from $M$ to $A$(The sets needn’t be disjoint) , why is this true?

Comment: The problem is that the image of a dedekind finite set may be dedekind infinite[ Hellrich 4.3]

Comment: @Logic: You're right, in general this not true. If $P$ is a Russell set, the countable union of pairs, $P_n$, such that $P$ is Dedekind-finite, let $A_p=P_n\setminus\{p\}\cup\{n\}$ where $n$ is the unique index such that $p\in P_n$, then $\{A_p\mid p\in P\}$ is a Dedekind-finite family of Dedekind-finite sets, and the union is $P\cup\omega$. However, if you read the question *closely*, you will notice that the union is assumed to be pairwise disjoint. Now that we've clarified all that there is to be clarified, we can move on.

Comment: Isn’t that the proof given in Herrlich’s  book? It’s great that this question was fully clarified, thanks a lot!

Comment: Also perhaps, this should be added to the answer to make it more complete, even though, the question does not ask for it, it’s a natural next question to come up with.

Comment: @Logic: I don't think it's a good idea to edit some old answer with information that nobody asked for.