# Union of Dedekind-finite sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$F$ is Dedekind-finite if for every $A\varsubsetneq F$ we have $A<_cF$. Need help to prove that if $F,G$ are Dedekind-finite sets, $F\cap G=\emptyset$  then $F\cup G$ is also Dedekind-finite.

Thnak you!

Comment: This is a special case of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/264136/8348).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:** If $A$ is Dedekind-infinite, then $A$ has a countably infinite subset. Show that if $F\cup G$ has a countably infinite subset, then either $F$ or $G$ has a countably infinite subset.

Comment: need to ask this. without the axiom of choice how can i derive that if $F$ has a countably infinite subset then it is not Dedekind-finite? I think it's wrong to say that if $F$ is infinite then is DEdekind-infinite withou the AC.\

Comment: Yes, the proof is the same as the proof that $\Bbb N$ is not Dedekind-finite. This is a characterization of Dedekind-finiteness in $\sf ZF$, assuming the axiom of [countable] choice, we have that every infinite set is Dedekind-infinite. But it's of no importance to your question.

Comment: this is because $2\mathbb N=_c\mathbb N$. But could you write me the proof,because i'm a litle confused:S

Comment: If $X$ has a countably infinite subset, $\{x_n\mid n\in\Bbb N\}$ consider the map $x\mapsto\begin{cases}x_{n+1} & x=n\\ x&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$ and show it is a self-injection which is not surjective; and in the other direction if $f\colon X\to X$ is an injective function which is not surjective, $x\in X$ which is not in the range of $f$ defines a countably infinite subset with $f$: $\{f^n(x)\mid n\in\Bbb N\}$ (use injectivity of $f$ to show this set is infinite).